# Double precision failing - Can't use Big-decimal

Tags: java

Problem: Double minus another double is returning unaccurate results.

Usual solution: Use big decimal to perform calculations.

I can't use this because it's in the middle of a game loop, can only set big decimal with a value when it's created with *new*, within a game loop I'm running out of memory.

What solution?

Here's the code:

```
public void UpdateStatsBar(double WorldPopulation, double WorldDead)
{
    Number = mOriginalPopulation - WorldPopulation;
}
```

The kind of numbers I'm using go into the billions and go tens of digits deep (averages for stats) example: 1432,323,234.234215232425322342

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: You need numbers bigger than 9223372036854775807?

Comment: Thanks, just reading that now.

Comment: Well it's decimal also, when you subtract it from another number it causes a slight miss calculation.

Comment: @AbakizMyth no, it is not decimal thats Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Yes!!! :) as suggested by Peter. World populations should not be decimal

Comment: How can you have `0.234215232425322342` of a person?

Comment: @PeterLawrey sometimes games get strage :-) (Joking - totally agree with all points of your answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't have a decimal number of people live or dead, I would use `long`.

Can you provide an example of the numbers you are using which are not producing accurate results?

BTW: If you use whole numbers less than nine thousand trillion, even `double` will produce accurate results.

BTW2: If you create `new BigDecimal` like mad but don't retain them you will hurt performance but you won't run out of memory.  If you are running out of memory its not due to use BigDecimal.  I suggest you use a memory profiler to find the true cause of the problem.

An example

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.ZERO;
long l = 0;
double d = 0;
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        bd = bd.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
        l++;
        d++;
    }
    System.out.println("counting bd: " + bd + " l: " + l + " d:" + d);
}
```

prints number counting with BigDecimal, long and double.  The format for double is different but the value is the same.

```
counting bd: 100000000 l: 100000000 d:1.0E8
counting bd: 200000000 l: 200000000 d:2.0E8
counting bd: 300000000 l: 300000000 d:3.0E8
... deleted ...
counting bd: 1900000000 l: 1900000000 d:1.9E9
counting bd: 2000000000 l: 2000000000 d:2.0E9
counting bd: 2100000000 l: 2100000000 d:2.1E9
counting bd: 2200000000 l: 2200000000 d:2.2E9
... deleted ...
```

Even with `-mx2m` limiting the heap to 2 MB it doesn't run out of memory.

Comment: reducing GCs is one of the reasons I don't use BigDecimal, but you won't be "running out of memory"